# Time complexity of this while loop?

Tags: while-loop, time-complexity

What's the time complexity of this loop?

```
j=2
while(j <= n)
{
    //body of the loop is Θ(1)
    j=j^2
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
j = 2
```

and each loop :
    j = j^2

The pattern is :

```
2     = 2^(2^0)
2*2   = 2^(2^1)
4*4   = 2^(2^2)
16*16 = 2^(2^3)
```

Which can be seen as :

```
2^(2^k) with k being the number of iteration
```

Hence loop stops when :

```
2^(2^k) >= n
log2(2^(2^k)) >= log2(n)
2^k >= log2(n)
log2(2^k) >= log2(n)
k >= log2(log2(n))
```

the complexity is log2(log2(n))

Comment: can you explain why it would be Log2(n)?

Comment: Yes sorry, i was on my mobile phone and planned to explain more when in front of a computer. And the answer was wrong on top of that ...